# Нестандартная папка загрузки для ckeditor

Tags: php, ckeditor

Необходимо настроить папку загрузки изображений вместо стандартной `userfiles/images`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Адрес папки загрузки будет постоянно меняться, поскольку для каждой статьи на сайте - отдельная папка (заданная переменной `$uploaddir`). Как задавать в `ckeditor` эту папку? Версия *CKEditor 4.4.7 (revision 3a35b3d)* и *KCFinder 2.51*.

Answer (score 1):

Папку можно динамически задавать.

- В **KCFinder** в файле config.php настраивать в массиве конфига
  $_CONFIG ключ 'uploadDir' нужным значением.
- В случае **CKFinder** в config.php переменные `$baseUrl`/`$baseDir`.

*Например:*

1. брать из [сессии](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Set-CKFinder-Image-path-dynamically.#post-18958):

   ```
   $baseUrl = $_SESSION['ckfinder_baseDir'];
   ```
2. прямо в config.php встроить дополнительную логику, как вариант
   получать сессию авторизованного пользователя и на основе её
   устанавливать путь для изображений:

   ```
   if (CheckAuthentication()) {
       $baseUrl = '/upload/userfiles/' . Auth::instance()->get_user()->id . '/';
   }
   else {
       $baseUrl = '/upload/userfiles/unregistered/';
   }
   ```